# 404 error client error installing pip for pygame on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame

I was trying to get pygame and it spat back this error.

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/user/

I had used this command in the galliumos terminal

`python3 -m pip install -U pygame -- user`

I had to take out most of the error to post this but that is the last line in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space between -- and user. Change it to `--user`

Comment: that looked like it worked, but when i did it the first time it had a progress bar and everything. was that supposed to come up again, or did something go wrong?